# What can I do (besides a rollback) if I disagree with an edit of my post?

Tags: support, edits, rollbacks

Suppose I consider someone's edit of my post bad or useless.
I do a rollback.
Now I want to draw attention of moderators to the user who did this bad edit.
What should I do in this case?

Update:
Sometimes when I see some users often edit others' posts and their edits are either useless or even bad, I ask the question: **What reason are they doing it for?** Maybe they get something for it? It looks like there is some incentive for them that I don't know. But if it is, then this incentive doesn't work well and gets these users to do useless and bad edits.

Comment: You can flag your own post with a custom mod flag and explain what happened.

Comment: Why do you want to draw the attention of moderators? If the only problem was one edit to your post (which you already fixed by rolling back), there's nothing else they really should be doing about it unless it was really bad (like to the level of breaking the CoC).

Comment: One bad edit does not require mod intervention, unless it's something extreme as said in other comment here by Laurel. Only if you see pattern of bad edits from same user, then you can custom flag one of your posts and explain, as Kevin said in yet another comment.

Comment: I take it you're referring to [this edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/345985/2), which you rolled back shortly before posting this? Can you explain what's so bad about this edit that you felt the need to roll it back in the first place, let alone get the moderators involved?

Comment: I don't think your question should be downvoted so hard; it's a question others might have, although I think it may have been asked and answered already. Sorry if my edit was upsetting.

Comment: @F1Krazy Yes, you're right, this is the edit I didn't like. I'm glad you gave me the opportunity to discuss it more specifically. First, I can't understand what's useful in that edit - it looks like the editor had some other goal than to do the original post better. **What is this goal?** I'd like to deal with it. Second, why remove my bold type from the numbers near the examples? This obviously makes the post worse in terms of visibility.

Comment: @Loviii I disagree with you that the edit didn't make the post better. It was a good edit mainly because it included helpful text about where the link was going ("From an answer on ELL" instead of just  "ell.stackexchange.com"). I would be confused about why it is linking to `ell.stackexchange.com`. The removal of the bold from numbers is subjective. But I also agreed with that edit because those numbers don't need to be bolded.

Comment: To answer your question from your update: Users with less than 2000 reputation get reputation points for each edit, but that's only if it is approved by their peers, and that mechanism prevents actual bad edits from going through. Users with more than 2000 reputation (such as the user who edited your question) don't get any reputation for their edits and do purely for the betterment of the community.

Comment: @CaveJohnson the user ColleenV did [7122 edits](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/9161/colleenv?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=1)! Without an extra incentive? I don't believe in it. I'm convinced a great deal of these edits don't make much sense and were done not "for the betterment of the community" as you said but for something else. P.S.: That's my point. I don't want to seem rude.

Comment: @Loviii without any incentive. Most people are contributing without any incentive here. Including current and former moderators and generally highly active users. No need to search for a foul play where it almost never happens.

Comment: I totally believe it.

Comment: @Loviii it's not rude outright, but apart of being totally wrong, you are essentially judging someone without knowing them. Don't do that, IRL as well as here on SE. What makes you think you know the motives of a different person?

Comment: It’s really weird that you’re talking about me instead of talking to me. If you want to know why I do something, just ask. I do everything I do on ELL because I enjoy doing it. Most of those edits are just tags to try to group related questions. I know of at least one other person on SE that enjoys tidying up posts as much as I do - they’ve got almost 10k edits here on Meta. (https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors).

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda i) You wrote: "_ you are essentially judging someone without knowing them_". But I judge only what I see - only those multiple edits because I see them. And you exaggerate as if I judged something else. ii) You wrote: "_Don't do that, IRL as well as here on SE_". So your point is that I should believe in all that I was told by someone or in all that someone or something wants to seem? That is, you don't use your experience to define in what you believe and in what you don't? It seems to me we're talking about different things and I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Loviii no. You can't see people's thoughts and motives and yet you clearly assume the motives are bad. That's what I meant.

Comment: Everyone here is trying to tell you that you are mistaken and please rid yourself of your prejudices because you are insinuating that good and altruistic people are committing petty acts. No one has done anything wrong to you; all that has been done is an improvement to your post that you didn't want and reversed. What is the crime in that? The crime of wanting your well-being and yours continuous improvement.

Answer (score 17):

My edit was intended to be helpful. If you didn't like it, then you did the right thing by rolling it back. I'm not sure what else you would like to have happen?

There's [more information about community editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing) in the Help Center.

You can 'ping' an editor in the comments of the post they edited if you want to discuss the edit. (Use `@username`...; there might not be autocomplete, but the editor is still notified.)

Comment: Maybe the removal of the userid from the link is what triggered this. By removing it you "denied" them a chance on the announcer badge.

Comment: @rene Ah I didn't consider that. Regardless, I was just trying to make it clear where the link was going. I don't really think about badges.

Comment: You can fix it by adding your own userid ;)

Comment: Lol I would never. I was just trying to multitask, and I suck at it, especially when on my phone.

Comment: It was a good edit.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I thought so, but it wasn’t so significant that I would try to force it on an author who didn’t want it. It was just a tweak.

Answer (score 8):

Usually moderators don't need to be informed about a single bad edit. After all if it's your post you can simply roll back the edit.

If there's a pattern of bad edits

- a user is repeatedly editing your post in a way you think makes it significantly worse even after you've rolled back their previous edits
- a user is editing lots of other people's posts in a way you think makes them significantly worse

or the edit has introduced spam links, rudeness or obscenities then yes, moderators need to get involved. Moderators can send messages to users to ask them to stop and suspend them if their problematic behaviour continues.

However you need to take an "assume good faith" attitude to edits because moderators certainly will and if you flag posts where the edit is OK your flag will simply be declined.

Some people don't like their posts being edited but it's a normal part of the process here. People who are usually far more experienced in understanding what makes a good post here will often try to improve your post even though they get very little reward for doing so. Such altruism is to be welcomed rather than condemned.

The [edit to this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/345985/2) for instance changes the link text so that it's more readable and we get more context as to what the link is and we certainly don't encourage more bold than is absolutely necessary in posts - i.e. usually none at all is best. So this is a useful edit. Ideally I'd like to see it use markdown numbering and the edit doesn't fix that but overall it's an improvement.

FWIW, if that edit was flagged on the site I moderate, I'd decline the flag. There's nothing here that needs a moderator to step in except perhaps to explain to you why this particular one was generally helpful, as I've tried to do in this answer.

Comment: I thought about changing the numbering, but left it alone because the author used the parens further down and I didn’t want to undo something that was obviously intentional and didn’t really affect the readability. Believe it or not I was trying to respect the author’s intent. I’m a bit surprised they’re so annoyed over it they refuse to talk to me lol.